# jqGrid not displaying even after including all files in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery

i tried with the following code .jqGrid not displaying.can someone please help?

//start
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#theGrid').jqGrid({

           height:500 ;
            colNames: ['Column1', 'Column2']


        });





      });

      //end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define colModel property of JQGrid. colNames is only used to display the column header text.